# Excel VBA correct/efficient formula population

Tags: excel, vba

Good Afternoon,

I have been developing solutions in VBA for going on 6 years now. A lot of what I have learned along the way has been sourced from SO in that time, so finally I get a chance to say THANK YOU!

Today I have come to the conclusion that I need to post a question that has been bothering me for years. So - one of the things I do most often in VBA for Excel is to populate defined ranges with results from formulas applied to the range in question. Until now I have used the below method to accomplish this:

```
Sub CalculateField()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim RecordStop As Long

Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
RecordStop = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MyRange)

'Apply Formula
Range("M2:M" & RecordStop).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-7]=1,IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(RC[-2],""|"",1),R1C12:R[-1]C[-1],1,FA  LSE)),0,1),0)"

'Drop Formula, keep values
Range("M2:M" & RecordStop).Value = Range("M2:M" & RecordStop).Value

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

What I have found is that, although this method works, with larger files/more complex formula the hit I take in performance is HUGE! Now, I know that there must be a more efficient way to derive the results of the formula and inject them directly into the sheet where one wants the results to come back to as values. In the above method I first calculate the results then overwrite the "Formulas" with the "values"(results). I am currently working on a file that will need 21 calculated fields and average between 100k - 400k records.

I fear the time has come for me to learn a better way, the proper more professional way to do this. I have searched here and via the mighty google for examples on how to do this. I have found posts on SO describing what I think is part of the solution, but have had difficulty finding a specific simple example I can follow to implement. I think the correct method involves one or all of the following:

1. Arrays
2. Dictionaries
3. Collections

... I hope you guys can point me in the right direction. This, once solved, I feel will greatly up my game in VBA development. I have been hesitant to delve into this as I am self educated and never really thought I would get this far as it is not my primary role, but would love to get past this now so I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

BTW; I am pretty good at self learning, so if by chance there is already a post that can get me there just point the way. Again, in searching I could not find what I was looking for so I apologize if that was a result of not knowing how to (words to describe) look for the answer.

Comment: It's a very good question, but I'm not sure that there will be a very good answer.  So much will depend on the specific formula that needs to be evaluated that I doubt if anyone will be able to come up with a one-size-fits-all solution.  I fear that the question will get closed as "too broad".  :(

Comment: Looping over the range and filling an array with the resulting values, and then dumping the array to the range (in one fell swoop) is almost certainly going to be loads faster, because there's no dependencies that will recalculate (on that note, you've disabled `ScreenUpdating` and `DisplayAlerts` but you didn't set `Calculation = xlCalculationManual`, you might try that just remember to revert to `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` before you exit the sub.

Comment: Specific to your example, it's difficult to surmise the proper approach, but I think first would be to pull all of your sources into Arrays, manipulate the arrays in memory, then write the final Array in one step to the target sheet.  I'd also implement an Application.EnableEvents = False. Adding that last but might just boost your performance significantly without doing anything else. Also, with calcs off, you can target just Range("M2:M" & RecordStop) for a calc before writing values.

Comment: so if you can disable the interim calculations, then maybe that will provide enough of a performance gain for you. worth a shot. Otherwise, you could try translating that formula to pure VBA which might also help, but you'd have to do the performance testing to really be sure.

Comment: @YowE3K - Thank you for correcting my original post

Comment: @DavidZemens - Yes, this sounds like the alternative. My question would then be how to "and filling an array with the resulting values, and then dumping the array to the range (in one fell swoop)". There must be a post on this site that provides and example for this. Now that I know the appropriate terms (thanks), I'll try to search for that method. By chance would you happen to know of such a posting to point me to?

Comment: yes I'll see what I can dig up but have you tried the other answer below yet? curious to know if disabling calculation will make a noticeable improvement?

Comment: @flaZer - Yes, similar to what David mentioned. The question is how? Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I am searching now for those key terms.

Comment: *How* will be pulling apart your formula in such a manner that you can write it to operate in a loop. I never work with R1C1 reference style, can you ELI5 this part of your formula?  It looks like you're trying to test whether a value exists in a range of cells. `IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(RC[-2],""|"",1),R1C12:R[-1]C[-1],1,FALSE)),0,1)`  In particular, what is the `R1C12:R[-1][C-1]` representing? For any given row on the worksheet, what range does this identify? Your Vlookup is returning the first column, so perhaps `Match` or `CountIf` would be more efficient?

Comment: Because `If(IsError(Match(RC[-2]&""|1"",R1C1:R[-1],False)),0,1)` might evaluate the same way, and might be faster, IDK. Or, `IF(COUNTIF(R1C1:R[-1],RC[-2]&""|1")>0,1,0)`. But I'm not 100% sure about those range addresses in R1C1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might start with this before tinkering a bunch.

If you don't get a performance boost, I'd then consider pulling your source data into Arrays, modify them in code, then write your results in a one line of code write back to your cells.

Here's a great link for working the Array route: [VBA Arrays And Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

```
Dim PrevCalc As XlCalculation
With Application
    PrevCalc = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .Cursor = xlWait
    .Calculate
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
Dim RecordStop As Long

Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
RecordStop = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MyRange)

'Apply Formula
With Range("M2:M" & RecordStop)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-7]=1,IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(RC[-2],""|"",1),R1C12:R[-1]C[-1],1,FA  LSE)),0,1),0)"

    'Calc only the target
    .Calculate

    'Drop Formula, keep values
    .Value = .Value
End With 'Range("M2:M" & RecordStop)

With Application
    .Cursor = xlDefault
    .Calculate
    .Calculation = PrevCalc
    '.ScreenUpdating = True 'Not Needed...
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks I will incorporate this scheme to the tops of all subroutines going forward. I was surprised that this gut down on run time by 20% (total run time still > 2.5 hrs). Still a far cry from the performance I would like to have but at least now I have this and know for sure its time to learn about "Arrays in memory".

Comment: You may get a speed bump using the "with" clause, but not really sure. Regardless, I've added it to the solution.

Comment: A whole new world of possibilities! Thanks guys, I think the combination of the above standard start/end protocol and Arrays is the solution. Now to studying the "how". Much appreciated!